# i need to export data to pdf in specfic format

Tags: pdf, export, itext

i am using this function to export data from database to pdf but its output like table ... i want to export a specfic row in format like :

```
id : 
Name : 
Gender :
Salary :
```

how do i do this ..
thanks in advance

```
public void ExportToPDF()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeId , EmployeeName , EmployeeGender , EmployeeSalary , isActive FROM Employee", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView gridview1 = new GridView();
        gridview1.AllowPaging = false;
        gridview1.DataSource = ds;
        gridview1.DataBind();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DataSet.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gridview1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4 , 10f , 10f , 10f , 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc , Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: embeed your data into html so that you can get same layout into PDF as well

Comment: That are many different ways to solve this problem @MohdSadiqGaur, but converting the data to HTML first and then use `HTMLWorker` to create the PDF is probably the worst option.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [UnitedStates](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/UnitedStates) example. For the sake of simplicity, I don't use a database but a CSV file. It should be very easy to adapt the example so that it accepts it data from a database rather than by parsing a CSV.

The key class you need is `PdfPTable`. For instance, if `databaseObject` is an object that you created to store the data from your database (e.g. the contents of a record), you need something like this:0

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("Id:");
table.addCell(databaseObject.getId());
table.addCell("Name:");
table.addCell(databaseObject.getName());
```

I see that you are using `HTMLWorker` in your code. This is problematic for two reasons:

1. It implies that you first convert all your data to XHTML. This costs processing time and if you don't need XHTML, then that time is wasted.
2. The `HTMLWorker` class is obsolete. It is no longer supported. If you do want to convert XHTML tables to PDF, you should use XML Worker as is done in these examples

Obviously, you can solve your problem in many other ways. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) and you'll discover that you could also create a template (see for instance [state.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/state.pdf)) and then fill this form like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    fields.setField("name", "CALIFORNIA");
    fields.setField("abbr", "CA");
    fields.setField("capital", "Sacramento");
    fields.setField("city", "Los Angeles");
    fields.setField("population", "36,961,664");
    fields.setField("surface", "163,707");
    fields.setField("timezone1", "PT (UTC-8)");
    fields.setField("timezone2", "-");
    fields.setField("dst", "YES");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

That is shown in the [FillForm](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillForm) example.

It's a pity that, with the abundance of documentation that can be found online (of which I only use a handful of examples), you chose a code snippet that doesn't come close to doing what you wanted to do.

Comment: Read the example: `src` is the path to the form; `dest` is the path to the resulting PDF. There is **plenty of documentation**, please read it!